# pattern to create a common interface to access database in js

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

i am trying to create one common js file to interact with database so that i don't need to manage separate methods to mange CRUD operation for different data set.

i have done it in two different ways but not sure which one is better , in terms of memory usage. I am not much aware about the javascript patterns so if anyone has some batter idea then feel free to post.

***here is pattern #1***

```
var DB = (function(){

    var dbInstance;


    return {

       getInstance: function () {

              // code 

              return dbInstance;
        },
         storeData:function(documentName, data){

         // code
         }
       };



})();
```

***pattern #2***

```
var DB = {

    dbInstance : null,

    getIntance : function (){


        return dbInstance;
    },

    storeDatabase : function (documentName, data){
    }

};
```

Comment: I would say your pattern #1, is the better one.  Only because it gives you scope for private data etc.